# CSS:hover issue when trying to display an opaque textbox

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to get the CSS:hover working correctly.

I am trying to display a textbox that has the opacity set to 0 when you hover over "My Website". I have achieved something similar with an image but cannot get it working with just text.

I have tried a:hover and p:hover, both do not work.

```
<div class="site">
                <p style="padding: 10px;"><a href="myWebsite.html" id="Home">My Website</a></p>
                <p id="siteText">This is my primary website where all the information you might require on me is available! This site is also a demonstration of my work; however, external reviews are available on the website!</p>
            </div>

#siteText {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    text-align: center;
    width: 475px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#Home a:hover + #siteText {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several fundamental issues with your markup.

1. You had the `a` element *inside* a `p` element *then* the `siteText` content.  Therefore, the selector `a:hover + #siteText` **could not work**, because the `a` and `#siteText` were *not* immediate siblings.
2. In your CSS, you had `#Home a:hover`, where `#Home` **was** the `a` element.  This should have been simply `#Home:hover`.
3. Some of your other styles for the `#siteText` (transform, position, etc) were causing it to appear off-screen, so I've removed them below to demonstrate the adjusted HTML / CSS works.

Also, I'd like to recommend that you *not* use ID's for things like this.  Instead, think in a global fashion.  That is, use a class / markup combination that is repeatable without having to keep adding more ID's to your CSS.  In the example below, I changed from `#siteText` (ID) to a *class* of `.tooltip` - and, tweaked the CSS so that now, anytime you have an `a` element immediately followed by an element with the class of `tooltip`, you'll have a functioning hover effect.

Below is a working snippet:

```css
.tooltip {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  width: 475px;
  padding: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.pad-vertical {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

a:hover + .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <div><a class="pad-vertical" href="myWebsite.html" id="Home">My Website</a>
    <p class="tooltip">This is my primary website where all the information you might require on me is available! This site is also a demonstration of my work; however, external reviews are available on the website!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
I've added some padding to the `a` element.  NOTE that I've done this again through a class, so that you can use the class on `a` elements where you may want padding like this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how would I add padding to this as in the CSS and in the HTML adding padding doesn't change anything.

Comment: Padding to what element, exactly?  If you mean around the `a`, then I'd do something like `a { display: inline-block; padding: 10px 0; }` (or similar).

Comment: I do mean to the 'a' yes but the code you supplied in your above comment doesn't work for what I wish it to do. This has really confused me because from my POV that should work? (No padding is being applied to the 'My Website' text at all)

Comment: Ignore my above comment. It was me being silly. Back to CodeAcademy I guess! Thank you for all your help. Marked as best answer!

Comment: Glad I could help.